# On Item Added event on an Drop Down List (Option selector)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given a drop down list, is there any way to subscribe a javascript even which will be fired when a new item is added to the list?

I'd like something like the following to work

```
$("select").itemAdded(function(value, text) { 
    alert(text + " has just been added to the list of options");
});

$("select").append($("<option></option").val("1").html("Something"));
//results in alert of "Something has just been added to the list of options"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for all browsers (including explorer, which is a bugger about this sort of thing).

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = 'The visual value';
option.value = 'Th submitted value';
$("select")[0].options.add(option);
```

EDIT:
I should probably stop being slack and give you the full code to make this work as a jQuery plugin.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.add_option = function(options) {
        var config = {
            value:0,
            text:0
        }
        config = $.extend(config, options);
        return this.each(function() {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = config.text;
            option.value = config.value;
            $(this)[0].options.add(option);
            alert(config.text+ " has just been added to the list of options");
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id_of_select_dropdown').add_option({text:'My new text value', value:'new'});
});
```

Comment: Not entirely sure why someone thought this warranted a negative vote - there's nothing wrong with what I've written as far as I can see.

Comment: It doesn't in any way answer the question he asked. He already knows how to add an option; indeed the question includes code to do it. He wants an event handler to let him know when it happens. Your answer doesn't do that.

Comment: I gave you an upvote for effort, but Craig is right, it doesn't answer the question, I am interested in a way to be notified when ever an option is added to a select, and that option can be added in any manner.

Comment: I added an alert to the code I wrote so you can see where the notification can be added into the method. As long as you use that method to add options you should be able to get the notification - if you want to use *any* methodology to add options you're out of luck.

Comment: *Any* methodology is exactly what he's asking for. I don't know a way to do this, BTW, though it's possible that a way exists.

Comment: It's possible the DOM events DOMNodeInserted or DOMAttrModified might be useful if you were trying to do this through any method, but they wont work in all browsers.